# How can I run NodeJS in Docker with MongoDB and RabbitMQ?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, rabbitmq

How can I run NodeJs in Docker and Connect it with MongoDB and RabbitMQ?
Do I need to run it in with `docker-compose`?

And also I need 2 environment

1. Run nodejs application in a development environment with `nodemon`.
2. The Second environment is production experiment `node app.js`

I found this `docker-compose` yml, but I can not understand how to connect it from nodejs

```
services:
    rabbitmq:
        image: rabbitmq:3-management-alpine
        container_name: rabbitmq
        environment:
            RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE: ${RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE}
            RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: ${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER}
            RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: ${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS}
```

Comment: I'd recommend reading through [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/), even if you're not using Compose; it has a pretty readable description of the overall networking environment and how to connect between containers.  For plain Docker there is a [Use user-defined bridge networks](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/#use-user-defined-bridge-networks) walkthrough, but it's not very conceptual and it includes a lot of low-level diagnostics that aren't usually needed.

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not need to run it with `docker-compose`.

I would recommend creating the following files:

- Dockerfile - production image build
- Dockerfile.dev - development image build

The Dockerfile.dev would look something like this:

```
FROM node:10-alpine
ENV PORT 8080
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . /usr/src/app

RUN npm install -g nodemon
RUN npm install

ENTRYPOINT ["nodemon", "/usr/src/app/server.js"]
```

The command to build the image: `docker build . -t node-app -f Dockerfile.dev`
The command to run the image: `docker run --rm -it -p 8080:8080 --network my-node-net -v "${PWD}:/usr/src/app" node-app`

---

Check out this example I saw: https://github.com/kelda/node-todo

> You also need to implement rmq and mongo client connections and run the official images inside the same network as the node-app

> All compose options can be translated into docker run commands